# Kal calendar in storyboard in combination with Tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, kal

I am working with a storyboard and a tabbar controller. Inside the storyboard I added a viewController and made it's class `AgendaViewController`. this Viewcontroller is embeded inside a navigation controller. Now in the .m of my AgendaViewController I have added this piece of code.

```
calendar = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
calendar.title = @"";
calendar.delegate = self;
dataSource = [[AgendaDatasource alloc] init];
calendar.dataSource = dataSource;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:calendar animated:YES];
```

This works. but when I push on the tabbarbutton again. (so I refresh my view) I get a white screen. The white screen is just the view of AgendaViewController

Any help?

Comment: Do you have anything in the viewDidLoad or init functions in your KalViewController?

Comment: I didn't change anything in my KalViewcontroller. Does it maybe have something to do with my navigationController ?

Comment: No, I have to custom buttons in my navigationbar. Put when I push on my tabbar button it does not do a segue. It's like it is just the rootViewController of my navigationController.

Comment: hmm, where are you setting up the custom buttons, IB? How did you set up the navigation controller IB? When you say you push on your tabbar and it doen't do a segue do you mean it's not going to a different view?